# Context.SaveChanges() to update record partially works only on first run

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

Really sorry bother but I am at a lost. The code below is giving me an headache. The first time it runs it partially update database, then it doesn't update it anymore. The first time cm.LogoPath changes from null to assigned value, but cm.LogoOriginalPath is not persisted to the DB (on breakpoint it shows that it has value and that Entity is set as "Modified").
All the other times it runs it doesn't update anything, even if I change the properties to be updated or the values to be persisted.

```
using (EMSDataModelContainer db = new EMSDataModelContainer())
{
    NotificationMsg msg = new NotificationMsg();
    ContactMaster cm = db.ContactMasters.Where(c => c.ContactMasterId == ContactMasterID).FirstOrDefault();
    if (cm.LogoPath != null)
    {
       msg = ImagesUpload.DeleteImage(cm.LogoOriginalPath, "", cm.LogoPath);
    }

    msg = ImagesUpload.UploadLogo(rauLogo.UploadedFiles[0].InputStream, "HotelLogo", HotelController.ContactMasterId.ToString(), rauLogo.UploadedFiles[0].GetExtension().ToString().ToLower());

    if (msg.MsgType.ToString() != "Error")
    {
        cm.LogoOriginalPath = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/seeam-imgs-test/" + "HotelLogo/" + HotelController.ContactMasterId.ToString() + "-Original" + rauLogo.UploadedFiles[0].GetExtension().ToString().ToLower();
        cm.LogoPath = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/seeam-imgs-test/" + "HotelLogo/" + HotelController.ContactMasterId.ToString() + ".jpg";
        db.ContactMasters.ApplyCurrentValues(cm); 
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Besides this way of saving setting had been working all over the application just fine.
One last bit of info, the LogoPath and OriginalLogoPath are 2 db table columns added later. I updated the model from database.

EDIT: To put this one simply, now something like this does not save the change:

```
using (EMSDataModelContainer context = new EMSDataModelContainer())
{
   ContactMaster c = context.ContactMasters.Where(i => i.ContactMasterId == ContactMasterID).Single();
   c.LogoOriginalPath = "Why is not saving";
   context.ContactMasters.ApplyCurrentValues(c);
   context.SaveChanges();
   context.Dispose();
}
```

Any direction would be appreciate it.

Comment: is `context.ContactMasters.ApplyCurrentValues(c);` necessary?

Comment: Not really. I tried also without it. But still same behavior.